# How to build a unidirectional synchronization from this Kafka topic to a table in Apache Hive?

Tags: apache-kafka, hive

We have data available in an Apache Kafka topic
We want to build a unidirectional synchronization from this Kafka topic to a table in Apache Hive
We can change the definition of the table in Hive as we want
The format of messages in Kafka is given, cannot be modified
Neither the Kafka nor Hive are in our control, we cannot install any plugins onto it.
We have a single server available with Linux and Java/Python installed

Comment: If you can't install plugins, what _can you use_? Are you using Spark/Flink? Kafka Connect? Presto?

Comment: we have a message in JSON format and I need to convert this using python then  create a table for hive without the use of any plugins

Comment: Why not use python to write to both Hive and Kafka?